# Gradle build failed in Unityv 2021.2.14 (gradle 6.1.1)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build.gradle

i try to bulid unity 2021.2.14 but Gradle build failed error occured as follows

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.2.14f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-6.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

*What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':launcher'.

> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':launcher:classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/6.1.1/gradle-6.1.1.pom
> Required by:
> project :launcher

What I try :

1. in baseProjectTemplate.gradle,change "classpath"

   ```
    dependencies {
        // If you are changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, make sure it is compatible with the Gradle version preinstalled with Unity
        // See which Gradle version is preinstalled with Unity here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html
        // See official Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility table here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
        // To specify a custom Gradle version in Unity, go do "Preferences > External Tools", uncheck "Gradle Installed with Unity (recommended)" and specify a path to a custom Gradle version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.3'
        **BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**
    }
   ```

to

```
    dependencies {
        // If you are changing the Android Gradle Plugin version, make sure it is compatible with the Gradle version preinstalled with Unity
        // See which Gradle version is preinstalled with Unity here https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html
        // See official Gradle and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility table here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle
        // To specify a custom Gradle version in Unity, go do "Preferences > External Tools", uncheck "Gradle Installed with Unity (recommended)" and specify a path to a custom Gradle version
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:6.1.1'
        **BUILD_SCRIPT_DEPS**
    }
```

to follow this referesnce.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-gradle-overview.html

and add gradleTemplate.properties

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx**JVM_HEAP_SIZE**M
org.gradle.parallel=true
android.enableR8=**MINIFY_WITH_R_EIGHT**
unityStreamingAssets=**STREAMING_ASSETS**
**ADDITIONAL_PROPERTIES**

//add this code

distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

could you tell me how to build successfully ?